# Eclipse marks lines as dead code

Tags: java, eclipse, dead-code

I have this function with some dead code, marked by Eclipse.

I have two lines that check a & b. Lines that check b are marked as null.

```
    public int[] runThis(List<Integer> buildIds, List<Integer> scenarios, boolean oflag) {

    int rating[] = new int[scenarios.size()];

    if(buildIds == null) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Building ID list is null!");
        return null;
    }

    if(scenarios == null) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Scenario list is null!"); //dead
        return null; //dead
    }

    return rating;      

}
```

Why does Ellipse make the two lines as dead? Any help? Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Is there any other code in that method? Maybe you've been dereferencing `b` before, which tells Eclipse that `b` can't be `null` at this point. In that case you should also get a warning like "unnecessary null check" at the `if (b == null)` line.

Comment: I don't know about *Eclipse* much but IntelliJ IDEA can analyze your code in real-time and warn you that some code is impossible to reach.  In your case, if IntelliJ were to detect that *b* was never *null*, then it would warn you that these two lines can never be reached because the condition *b == null** is always false.

Comment: @Joachim: that particular warning is configureable in Eclipse's settings. I believe it's by default turned off.

Comment: can you paste the whole method?

Comment: @BalusC: Oh, I didn't remember that. I probably turned it on as soon as I heard about it ;-) pretty useful these ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because you've already called `scenarios.size()` in your array constructor.  This guarantees `scenarios` isn't null or it will have thrown an exception by that point.

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation.  I hadn't realized that by evaluating something earlier it's guaranteed NOT to get there because of prior NPE, so hence: "Dead code" warning.